# Why can a raw type reference refer to a generic instance?

Tags: java, generics, reference, generic-collections, raw-types

Please help understand why

```
Map map1 = new HashMap<String,String>(); // This compiles
Map<Object,Object> map2 = new HashMap<String,String>(); // This does not.
```

As per my understanding

```
Map map1
```

is same as

```
Map<Object,Object> map1
```

---- Edit ----

When generics are not provided for reference map1 , compiler accepts the object creation with any generics. This to me seemed like map1 have implicit

```
<Object,Object>
```

generics applied.

So the question here is why compilation fails when map2 have explicit

```
<Object,Object>
```

generics applied.

For downvoters , the question for which this is marked as duplicate , does not answer my question directly.

Thanks Chetan and Pham , That explains!!!.

Comment: Have you tried using `Map<String, Sring> map2 = new HashMap<String,String>();` instead of `Map<Object,Object> map2 = new HashMap<String,String>();`

Comment: @Aakash Your comment is irrelevant.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I don't think it's a direct duplicate of the question you linked to. This question asks whether `Map` is the same as `Map<Object,Object>`

Comment: There is no type check done from compiler for 'map1', but for 'map2' and there generic types don't match.

Comment: your understanding is wrong , map1 != map2

Comment: I am voting to reopen this question as it's not a duplicate of the one it has been marked a duplicate of. The marked duplicate does not talk about raw types.

Comment: @ChetanKinger Exactly. I don't think the people who voted to close as a duplicate looked at the question closely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `Map<Object,Object> map2 = new HashMap<String,String>();`
>
> As per my understanding
>
> `Map map1`  is same as
>
> `Map<Object,Object> map1`

No. A `Map` is not the same as a `Map<Object,Object>`.

A reference of type `HashMap<T,T>` is a subtype of a reference of type `Map`. In other words, a reference of type `Map` can refer to an object of type `HashMap<String,String>`.

On the other hand, a reference of type `HashMap<T,T>` is not a subtype of a reference of type `Map<E,E>` (Even if `T` is-a `E` and `HashMap` is-a `Map`). In other words, a reference of type `Map<Object,Object>` can't refer to an object of type `HashMap<String,String>` even if `String` is-a `Object` and `HashMap` is-a `Map`.

If you are wondering why the rules for reference sub types in case of generics works this way, there is one explanation I can give based on my understanding. Generics are syntactic sugar and go through what is known as `type-erasure` once the code is compiled. That is, a `HashMap<String,String>` when compiled becomes a `HashMap`.

If the compiler allowed the statement `Map<Object,Object> map = new HashMap<String,String>`, it would mislead programmers to believe that the `Map` can only hold `String` key and values at runtime. This would be absurd since Generics go through `type-erasure` at compile time itself.

The statement `Map map = new HashMap<String,String>` is allowed on the other hand mostly for backward compatibility with legacy code.

Comment: Can the downvoter please leave a comment and let me know what is wrong with my answer? I believe that the only explanation for the downvote would be that the downvoter does not have the basic understanding of the Java programming language to understand my answer.

Comment: not the downvoter - but you're not likely to get an answer by pre-emptively insulting the downvoter :-) maybe it helps if you add a reference to "JLS 4.10.2. Subtyping among Class and Interface Types" to show that you are right.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Thanks for the upvote. I believe the downvote may have been due to a small typo in my answer which I corrected. Didn't deserve a downvote for a typo. Will quote the JLS. :)

Answer (score 0):

That is because when you use `new HashMap<String,String>();` the object can contain only String values.

But the variable `Map<Object,Object> map2` means that map2 can contain `Object` keys and values.

And using `Map<Object, Object>` is not the same as using `Map`. Its just that in the latter you are not using type safety, the former will show your errors during compilation itself but the latter will throw errors during Runtime.